# Refund on OpenERP (Odoo)

Tags: python, odoo, payment

I am creating a payment acquirer for OpenERP. The documentation is bad but I managed to achieve this by looking at paypal acquirer code. The issue is - I want to run custom code when invoice is being refunded - so the payment service would credit the monry back to the customer. I couldn't find anything relevant on docs so I am asking here.

Can someone just give me a hand understanding how to inject my code when the invoice is refunded?